# Use std::find on vector<class> to find matching class attribute

Tags: c++, vector, find

Say I have a class `myClass` with 3 attributes in the constructor (`string value`, `int pos`, `int pos_2`).

Now I make a `vector` of objects of said class.

How would I search through `vector<myClass>` to find the index of any class objects with a `string` that matches a given `string`?

---

**Example**:

Here's a (non-functional) attempt at finding a class object that has the string `hello` as its `string value`:

```
std::string to_find = "hello";
std::vector<myClass>::iterator duplicate_it;
duplicate_it = std::find(subrelation_vector.begin()->value, subrelation_vector.end()->value, to_find);
int duplicate_pos = *duplicate_it->pos;
```

Comment: Use `std::map` or `std::multimap` per attribute for more quick search. The values of map and vector for this case better make as std::shared_ptr<myClass>